# using Adapter to display ListView Mono for android

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, adapter, xamarin.android

I created a `ListView` and to populate it I'm using `Adapter`.

`GetView()` of `Adapter` class is as follows:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.LayoutInflater;
if (convertView == null) 
{
    convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.List_MktData, null);
}

DataRow dr;
object[] row;

if(position==0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In position 0");
    dr = result.Rows[0];
    row=dr.ItemArray;

    tvCMPValue.Text=row[0].ToString();
    tvPrevClose.Text=row[1].ToString();
    tvOpen.Text=row[2].ToString();
    tvHigh.Text=row[3].ToString();
    tvLow.Text=row[4].ToString();
    tvClose.Text=row[5].ToString();
}

else if(position==1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In position 1");
    dr = result.Rows[1];
    row=dr.ItemArray;

    tvPercChgValue.Text=row[0].ToString();
    tvPrevCloseValue.Text=row[1].ToString();
    tvOpenValue.Text=row[2].ToString();
    tvHighValue.Text=row[3].ToString();
    tvLowValue.Text=row[4].ToString();
    tvCloseValue.Text=row[5].ToString();
}
```

where all elements starting with **tv** are `TextView` within a `ListView`.

Now the problem is when I run this code, I get the following output as shown in Screen shot.

i.e. Content of `Row1` and `Row2` gets displayed in `Row1' while`Row2` is showing correct data.

I know it is something related with `position` variable, but after spending lot of time on it, I'm still not able to crack it.

Note : Data is coming from `DataTable` having two rows.

1st row of `ListView` should be populated with 1st row of `DataTable` while 2nd row of `ListView` should be populated with 2nd row of `DataTable`.

I'm absolute beginner when it comes to *Mono for Android*, so any help appreciated...

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is: 2 rows that have a table in each row, each consisting of two rows.
What you want is: 2 rows in the `ListView` with a `LinearLayout` with *one* row of `TextViews` .

Then, do this for each call to `GetView`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.LayoutInflater;
if (convertView == null) 
{
    convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.List_MktData, null);
}

DataRow dr;
object[] row;

Console.WriteLine("In position " + position);
dr = result.Rows[position];
row = dr.ItemArray;

tvCMPValue.Text = row[0].ToString();
tvPrevClose.Text = row[1].ToString();
tvOpen.Text = row[2].ToString();
tvHigh.Text = row[3].ToString();
tvLow.Text = row[4].ToString();
tvClose.Text = row[5].ToString();
```

Solves two problems: less code and it should work.
Also, as you may notice, there is a gap between the two items in the list. this is a result of the first row (table) in the second row (list item), this is the header table row, not having any values.

Comment: then what about remaining textboxes of Row 2? How to populate them?

Comment: Could you post the contents of the `Resource.Layout.List_MktData` resource?

Comment: Based on you code above, will you only ever have two items in the list? You could use a table layout instead if this is the case.

Comment: got the solution, thnx a lot !